# Attempting to interact with the k8s container by websocket and client-go

Tags: kubernetes, containers

When I was trying to interact with k8s container, I found I can't get the container results, but what I inputed. Where is the problem?

```
func ExecCommandInPod(ctx context.Context, conn *websocket2.WsConnection, namespace, podName, containerName string) error {
    conf, err := k8sutil.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    handler := &websocket2.StreamHandler{
        WsConn:      conn,
        ResizeEvent: make(chan remotecommand.TerminalSize),
    }
    defer conn.WsClose()

    req := k8sutil.MustNewKubeClient().CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().
        Resource("pods").
        Name(podName).
        Namespace(namespace).
        SubResource("exec").
        VersionedParams(&v12.PodExecOptions{
            Command:   []string{"sh"},
            Container: containerName,
            Stdin:     true,
            Stdout:    true,
            Stderr:    true,
            TTY:       true,
        }, scheme.ParameterCodec)
    exec, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(conf, "POST", req.URL())

    if err = exec.StreamWithContext(ctx, remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:             handler,
        Stdout:            handler,
        Stderr:            handler,
        TerminalSizeQueue: handler,
        Tty:               true,
    }); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not stream execution: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I want to interact with k8s container, like linux terminal. I want to complete that with gin and websocket. Please help me.

Comment: You'll probably want to be adding the errors you get.

Comment: Consider interacting with your local containerized processes the same way you interact with Stack Overflow: use a network-accessible transport like HTTP or RabbitMQ, and don't try to manually run additional commands inside Pods.  This will insulate your application from changes in the container layout, it's easier to add replicas to handle additional load, and it doesn't require Kubernetes-specific API code or credentials.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found I need a line break to get the return value. The question has been solved. Thank you everyone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).